# Is it possible to use Civimail without unsubscribe / opt out option?

Tags: civimail

Our organisation uses Civimail to communicate with our members on a regular basis. Email is the only realistic way we have of communicating with them and informing them of legal notications, ballots etc as well as news and alerts. The presumption is that in ajoining as a member they agree to receive email communications from us.

A number of members use the opt out link on our mailings which then means they no longer receive any communication at all from us as their email address is now disabled in Civi.

Is there a way of either removing the opt out / unsubscribe links since by accepting membership they have opted in or a way of getting round the issue of members who have cut themselves off from the organisation they have joined.

We are using CiviCRM 5.14 Drupal 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pete's answer is technically correct, but from a user experience perspective - these folks are choosing to opt out, and there should ideally be a middle ground that meets everyone's needs.

My assumption is that you have mailings that *must* reach the members - legal notices, etc. - and then some non-mandatory communication (e.g. a newsletter) which is what folks opt out of.

If that's the case:

- Create one (or more) additional groups - mandatory communications, newsletters, special offers, etc.
- Add all the members to all the groups.
- Use the "unsubscribe" token rather than "opt out" token.
- Send mailings from the appropriate group.

With this approach, someone who opts out of one type of communication doesn't opt out of another.

You can combine this with Pete's approach and use a template that includes an "Unsubscribe" where it belongs, and omit it on mandatory communication.

Comment: another approach we used way back that eileen cooked up was a single pixel image (?) replacing the Unsub link - so the Unsub was there but no one saw it

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. There is an override option under Admin > CiviMail > CiviMail Component Settings

ie at civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/mailing?reset=1

> **Disable check for mandatory tokens**
>
> Don't check for presence of mandatory tokens (domain address; unsubscribe/opt-out) before sending mailings. WARNING: Mandatory tokens are a safe-guard which facilitate compliance with the US CAN-SPAM Act. They should only be disabled if your organization adopts other mechanisms for compliance or if your organization is not subject to CAN-SPAM.

[image]